# Embed animated SVG in HTML page, paused (without starting animation)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

You can embed an SVG file into into an (X)HTML 5 document:

```
<object data="anim.svg" id="svganim"/>
```

or

```
<img src="anim.svg" alt="embedded SVG"/>
```

But if `anim.svg` is animated, the animation will start playing as soon as the page loads.

**How can you embed an animated SVG file such that the animation starts out paused?** The user can then play the animation by pressing a button (using `unpauseAnimations()` in Javascript)

#### An inelegant way

```
window.onload = function() {
    var svg_anim = document.getElementById('svganim').contentDocument.rootElement;
    svg_anim.pauseAnimations();
};
```

Disadvantage: this doesn't work if the embedded SVG is in a different security context from the parent document. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to solve this is to make the animations not start automatically by changing the svg file (to add begin="indefinite" to any animations that start automatically). These animations can then be triggered by a call to `beginElement()` to the animation elements you want to trigger. If you have many such elements, it's probably easier to use `pauseAnimations()`.

However, with <img> elements you can't start the animations since no events will ever be fed into the svg itself, so that's not going to work there. And scripting is disabled in this case too, so you can't trigger or prevent animations that way either.

With <object>, <embed> or <iframe> you can do scripting, e.g like your suggestion. You can add a script tag as one of the first children of the svg root element of the svg file and in that <script> element call `pauseAnimations`. But you can also do it from the main document as you suggested.